# wso2 Oauth Mediator Issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 EI 6.1.1 and WSO2 Identity server of version 5.5.0. We have a requirement of using Oauth Mediator to validate the access token. I have a service provider registered with the identity server and generated the oauth2.0 bearer access token using curl command. I tried the Oauth2webservice to validate the authorization which was succeed and request going to identity server. But if I use the Oauth Mediator of WSO2 Integrator getting the below error message and the request is not going to identity server which was confirmed from the logs of identity server.Please help on it.Is there any other jar files or configuration settings needed for the same.

```
<oauthService remoteServiceUrl="https://localhost:9444/services/" username="admin" password="admin"/>

ERROR - OAuthMediator Error occured while validating oauth access token.java.lang.Exception: Error while validating OAuth2 request. at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.mediator.OAuth2TokenValidationServiceClient.validateAuthenticationRequest(OAuth2TokenValidationServiceClient.java:61).

Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null.at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and can't resolve, This bug has not been corrected yet

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5243